# <div>s go to full screen width on desktop but not mobile why?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm at a complete loss on what's pushing out my viewport.

I have `<div>`s which should stretch 100% across the screen but stop short, and I have no idea why.

I've been hacking at this for hours, and fixed the sideways scroll, I had padding on the `flex-keys` style which was forcing it too wide.  Removing this eliminated the scroll but simultaneously the full width `<div>`s started stopping a few px from the right of the screen.

I'd love somebodies intuitions. Or really how to go about hunting down the problem.

If you click through to the site I've put borders around every element using
`*{ border: 1px solid red; }`

So if someone can instantly see what's causing the trouble, that'd help.  The container `<div>`s for the hero-image and slideshow appear to exceed the viewport, but they're set to 100% so I have no idea why, or how to fix it.

I'd love some kind eyes.

https://pottertour.co.uk/index2.html

Comment: Please demonstrate this with a snippet, rather than a full website, because this feels like the kind of issue that you're going to solve entirely on your own simply by running through the exercise of forming a [mcve] that you can post here.

Comment: Adding the code you need to solve will not only help others find the exact problems causing this but as Mike said, it can help you realize what mistake you may have made when coding. i.e. Missing a closing tag or a bracket

Comment: Hey guys understood, will do so in future.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding from the following classes.

**index2.html:524**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm)
.flex-container {
width: 100%;
/* padding-left: 5px; */
/* padding-right: 5px; */
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

**styles-boxes-test.css:414**

```
.flex-container {
width: 100%;
/* padding-left: 5px; */
/* padding-right: 5px; */
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You may also need to reduce the size of the "60" in the "60 day money back guarantee" callout. It breaks the design at ~403px wide.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  So you have answered my question and I'll mark it right shortly (thanks so much!), but it leads to another - wth?  

1.  Surely padding shouldn't break the viewport?  The browser should just calculate back from the viewport width?  Huh?

2.  What is the solution then?  Text is super-ugly squashed up against the bezel edge of a mobile display.  What's the cleanest way to get padding that doesn't break the viewport?  
Is it the case I should nest 2 divs for each column, and place a margin on the inner div?  Bit verbose.  Thanks again. :)

Comment: There are issues with the interpretation of the "box model" that extend back generations of browsers. This is usually solved by having a "container" div that doesn't have any padding or margin. Within that div, is another one that does contain padding and margin. Here is a link to the W3Cs explanation of the "box model". https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Oh how mental.  I tried nesting with both spans and divs, didn't work, gave me horizontal scroll.  What's working is padding on paragraph elements, it's just nuts.  I've reduced the font size for the '60', thanks for all the tips.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck. Glad you found a solution that will work for you.